# Can I use a Bitmaps to pick up speed from Canvas.drawBitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, layer

Let me give you some substance to my question. I am currently drawing 2 or more full screen drawables to my canvas. The drawables in the foreground slide at different speeds and have large transparent sections to create a shifting scene. (Think side scroller game like mario. I believe they call this parallax)
I then follow that up with several smaller drawables in the foreground that move and do their own thing.
At present drawing all these drawables to my canvas is very taxing on my device. Is there a way to use Bitmaps to programmatically and dynamically layer them while maintaining the alphas, to achieve the same affect and reduce the number of times I call drawBitmap on my canvas?

Thanks

Comment: After getting more familiarized with the `Drawable` classes I'm convinced that there isn't a way to do it like I had originally hoped. But there is promise with using `Bitmaps` instead. I've managed to drop a lot of the time my app spends in `Canvas.drawBitmap` but then picked a lot of it back up in the methods that handle all the `Bitmap` work. The main problem I am having now is combining the Alpha channel onto the existing `Bitmap`. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? Thanks again.

Comment: ATM I am using the `.setPixels(pixels[], ...)` to layer my final Bitmap. I'm going to try and handle it with the `setPixel(...)` in a for loop instead. I think if I select the appropriate color and combine the alpha channels before I insert each pixel into the final Bitmap I can avoid progressing through the loop more than once and possible pick up a bunch of time and solve my Alpha problem.